# typescript array functions with custom object equals

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I want to use array functions (like contains, unique) which check equality with my own equals function.

For example:

```
let arr = [{id:1,..//some more},{id:2,..//some more},{id:3,..//some more}]
```

I want that this will return true, by using equals function that check the id only:

```
arr.contains({id:1,....}).
```

I tried to search by didn't find.

How can I do it? and generally how can I use my own equal function in typescript (like equals function in Java).

Comment: *"I want to use array functions(like contains, unique)"* JavaScript's array type doesn't have [*either* of those functions](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-properties-of-the-array-prototype-object). It does have `includes` (as of ES2016).

Comment: *"I tried to search by didn't find..."* Really? You couldn't, for instance, find [the MDN page on arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)? Which lists `find`, `forEach`, ... http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: You didn't understand my question. The functions name doesn't matter, I know all the function of array. I want to use all array functions with my custom equal function.

Comment: I understood your question just fine. Did you *look* at `find`?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the equality check used by array functions like `includes` or `indexOf`. But other array functions let you use a callback instead:

- `find` - Finds the first entry in the array for which your callback returns a truthy value
- `findIndex` - Finds the *index* of the first entry in the array for which your callback returns a truthy value
- `some` - Loops through an array calling your callback until it returns a truthy value (in which case `some` stops and returns `true`); if your callback never returns a truthy value, `some` returns `false`.
- `every` - Loops through an array calling your callback until it returns a falsy value (in which case `every` stops and returns `false`); if your callback never returns a falsy value, `every` returns `true`.

All of these are described, with linked detailed descriptions, on the [MDN array page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

So for example, "contains" with custom equality would be `some`:

```js
const a = [
  {id: 1},
  {id: 2},
  {id: 3}
];
console.log("Has 1? " + a.some(e => e.id == 1));
console.log("Has 4? " + a.some(e => e.id == 4));
```

Comment: *(If the example above uses `find`, hit refresh. \*yawn\* Need more tea.)*

Answer (score 1):

You can use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and test that the value returned is not undefined

Example:

```
let arr = [{id: 1, test: '1'}, {id: 2, test: '2'}];
const customEqual = i => i.id === 1;
const containsItemWithId1 = arr.find(customEqual) !== undefined;
```